# Biggest directional coefficient

Tags: derivatives

How do you get the greatest directional coefficient's exact points if you have the equation of the curve? 
This is not a mathematics problem. I have a mathematics problem, where I must count out at which points there is the greatest directional coefficient, and I don't now how to start. I thought of using first derivative and then put y`=0, but it is not right.
(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

When you said highest directional coefficient, I'm not sure if you mean highest *point*, which means a maximum/minimum? In that case, you would want to check points where $y'=0$.

Now, if you mean highest directional coefficient like highest *slope* or *rate of change*, then you would want to change where $y''=0$ or $y''$ doesn't exist.